# Display any value instead of null?

Tags: mysql, null

- Database: Tennis
- Table: Players
- Some of the Columns: playerno, first name, last name, leagueno.
- Task: If the league number is NULL, then give the value 1.
- Question: Can we do this without coalesce function ? or without any other function ?
- My code is wrong. I still see a null instead of 1. Besides, there is the unnecessary column due to the case.

Code:

```
use tennis;
select playerno, name, initials,leagueno,
case 
when leagueno = null then 1 
end
from players
where tennis.players.town = 'Stratford'
order by leagueno desc;
```

Please help me to do it correctly. I have the answer which uses coalesce. But i want to try another method.

Comment: why is the formatting system so complicated and unintuitive  ?

Comment: In short, nulls are an oddity in SQL.  You need to use leagueno IS null instead of leagueno = null.

Comment: You also probably want MySQL's [`ifnull` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull). Why do you want it done without using functions?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) to understand how StackOverflow does formatting.

Comment: did that, but null values appear as null in the 'case' column. I want those 1s to appear in the leagueno column instead.

Comment: You will need to read about [`SELECT` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), search for "alias".

Comment: @lanzz - only out of curiosity. If it can't be done that way, then i will use a function.

Comment: `CASE` can be considered a function with a weird call syntax. You're not avoiding functions by using `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
use tennis;

select playerno, name, initials,
case 
when leagueno is null then 1 -- note: is null instead of = null
else leagueno
end as leagueno -- This names the result column "leagueno", which may be useful
                -- depending on how you read the result
from players
where tennis.players.town = 'Stratford'
order by leagueno desc;
```

This basically makes the last column `leagueno` except that if it's `NULL`, you get `1` instead.

Comment: yes. it worked but with a small issue.
This code gets the result, but as another column, also called leagueno. I want the effects to be seen in the original leagueno column itself.

Book solution(works):

    select initials, name, coalesce(leagueno,1)
    from players
    where town = 'Stratford'

Comment: @user1499832 Check the first line of my select statement. Yours ends with `,leagueno` but mine doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, i did not notice. Thanks ! btw, on the side, which method is more efficient ? yours or the coalesce(-------) method mentioned in the above comments ?

Comment: @user1499832 I would be very surprised if the performance difference between those two methods was ever significant in real-world conditions. `coallesce` is probably easier/faster to read for experienced DB coders though, so I'd go with that.